# Is there a Dirichlet series that can be analytically continued to every point on the abscissa line?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^z}$$
be a Dirichlet series with convergence half plane ${\rm Re}z > \sigma_c$ where $\sigma_c\in\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: is it possible that for each point $z$ on the abscissa line ${\rm Re}z=\sigma_c$, $f$ can be analytically continued to $z$?

Comment: Does analytically continued mean that there is an analytical function on an open neighbourhood of the point that coincides with your function in the intersection of the domains?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz yes, but for different points on the abscissa line the continuation may be different.

Comment: No, it is standard theory that it cannot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation

Comment: @A.Pongrácz isn't Dirichlet eta functionby Paul an example for this? it can be analytically continued to the whole plane, and hence all points on the absissa line.

Comment: If it has an analytical continuation to the whole plane, then in what sense is the vertical line at 0 an abscissa to it? Maybe I misunderstood the question. So if you want, you can accept that answer.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz the analytical continucation of a function $f$ may appear in a different form from $f$ itself, here the contiuation can not be expressed as a Dirichlet series. Consider continuation of $1+z+z^2+\cdots$ outside the unit disc for example.

Comment: I know exactly what analytical continuation means. What does abscissa mean to you?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz may be there is something I'm wrong: for a power series it has a convergence circle, outside the circle the power serice diverges. For a  Dirichlet series it has a convergence half plane, but it may also converges for some region beyond the absissa line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirichlet eta function does this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function
It's an entire L-function whose series only converges for real part greater then zero.

Comment: But then how does it answer the question? It cannot be continued to the line of complex numbers whose real part is $0$.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz it can be continued to the whole complex plane by abel summation.

Comment: So I still don't understand how it answers the question. Maybe I am wrong, but I don't understand.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz maybe I missunderstand something:
He looks for a dirichlet series with a convergence abscissa without a pole. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, I am not sure anymore. Maybe the author of the post should clarify.

Comment: @PaulK: yes that's what I mean.